# net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 with Chromium based Browsers

Tags: java, rest, google-chrome, tomcat, chromium

I know there are already some questions regarding this issue but maybe I can give some additional input.
Problem:
I have a Tomcat 8.5 environment with a Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE Rest App.

The problem occuers at a request that should respond with a JSON payload of ~1 mio lines (approx. 19MB).
In Postman, SoapUI, Firefox, Safari and Chrome(on MacOS) it works perfectly but in all Chromium based Windows browers i get following error in the Browers console:
net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200
and the network tab says "Fehler" in the "Status" column of the targetted request.

The last packet I can see in Wireshark shows the following:
[image]
I can see a ClientAbortException in catalina.out.

I already tried not using our company proxy without success and disabling the Virusscanner is not that easy in a big company.